# How can i add a animation to a span using javascript when a letter is guessed correctly in a hangman game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a animation to my game when a word is guessed correctly, the below code changes the spans background color to green when a letter is correct and on standard the background color is set to orange (#ff6a00). I have tried to add transform rotate 20 degrees but does not do anything the color property does change to green if the letter = the letter. I am trying to add it to the first if. I don't want the final result to be for it to rotate 20 degrees when the letter is correct, this is just to test if the way I was doing it would work. The end result I want it to flip like a card and slowly reveal the letter.  [Image of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04AXM.png)

```
get puzzle() {
let puzzle = [];
if (puzzle != null) {
  this.word.forEach((letter) => {
    if (this.guessedLetters.includes(letter)) {
      puzzle.push({
        transform: "rotate(20deg)",
        letter: letter,
        color: "green",
      });
    } else if (letter === " ") {
      puzzle.push({
        letter: letter,
        color: "none",
      });
    } else {
      puzzle.push({
        letter: "*",
        color: "#ff6a00",
      });
    }
  });
  return puzzle;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a transition to animate your rotation, you can get examples [here](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/).

To support all modern browsers, the following styles should be used for transitions:

```
-webkit-transition
-moz-transition
transition
```

and for transforms:

```
-webkit-transform
-moz-transform
-ms-transform
transform
```

For example:

```
div {
-webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
-webkit-transform: translate(3em,0);
-moz-transform: translate(3em,0);
-o-transform: translate(3em,0);
-ms-transform: translate(3em,0);
transform: translate(3em,0);
}
```

Comment: ok i understand, if i add the animation i want to the desired span, how do i make the animation run if a if statement is true